# Python sum data from JSON with same key

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I have online JSON file where I have something like this:

```
{'skladiste': 1, 'sifra': '7138', 'nc': 0.8, 'vpc': 47.01, 'mpc': 55.0, 'stanje': 5.0, 'aktivan': 255, 'lokacija': '', 'atraktivanod': 0, 'atraktivando': 0}
{'skladiste': 2, 'sifra': '7138', 'nc': 0.8, 'vpc': 47.01, 'mpc': 55.0, 'stanje': 2.0, 'aktivan': 255, 'lokacija': '', 'atraktivanod': 0, 'atraktivando': 0}
```

Now I need to get that JSON data, sum 'stanje' for same key which is 'sifra' through whole JSON file. Is there any help?

I got JSON file data with this but I can not sum data

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
  
# import json
import json
# store the URL in url as 
# parameter for urlopen
url = "https://www6.eline.ba/bl/RestWebShop.svc/json/CjenovniciZaWeb/ee6e994652884578830402a297ef3a93/tobyshop"
  
# store the response of URL
response = urlopen(url)
  
# storing the JSON response 
# from url in data
data_json = json.loads(response.read())

# print the json response
print(data_json)
```

For example, there is 'sifra' 7138 repeated 2 times in this data with 'stanje' 5 and 2 and now I need to sum this two and export new data with only one ID 7138 and stanje with data of 7.

Comment: requirement is not clear.

Comment: The variable `data_json` contains a `dict` with all the key-value-pairs from the JSON file. You can read them and add values as needed.

Comment: @The6thSense I got a data from JSON but now I need go through whole JSON and SUM 'stanje' data with same ID which is in this case 'sifra'. For example, there is sifra 1001 2 times in this data, with 7 and 8 stock quantity (stanje) and in the end there needs to be a sum of this data, 15 and expored in new JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand after reading your comments, your goal is to have the same json as output, just grouping those elements that have the same 'sifra'.

These are the steps needed:

First step is to get the list of items from the json, that is inside the key 'cjenovnici':

```
original_list = data_json['cjenovnici']
```

Then you sort the list using 'sifra':

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key = itemgetter('sifra'))
```

And once the list is sorted you can use `groupby` to create a new list:

```
grouped_list = []
for key, value in groupby(sorted_list, itemgetter('sifra')):
  list_value = list(value)
  element = list_value[0]
  if len(list_value) >= 1:
    # if there is more than 1 element with the same 'sifra', sum 'stranje' of them
    element['stanje'] = sum(item['stanje'] for item in list_value)
  grouped_list.append(element)
```

Now you can replace the original list with the grouped list in data_json:

```
data_json['cjenovnici'] = grouped_list
```

And as final step you can save the data as a new json file:

```
with open('json_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data_json, outfile)
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I got you. 

But how can I SUM all data and print in format:

'sifra' - 'stanje'

Where 'sifra' is sifra and stanje is sum of all 'stanje' which contains same 'sifra' ?

Comment: @eldinhooo, I have modify the code after reading your comment. I hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the json the sum them.

**Code:**

```
output_dict = {}
dict_list = [{'skladiste': 1, 'sifra': '7138', 'nc': 0.8, 'vpc': 47.01, 'mpc': 55.0, 'stanje': 5.0, 'aktivan': 255, 'lokacija': '', 'atraktivanod': 0, 'atraktivando': 0},
{'skladiste': 2, 'sifra': '7138', 'nc': 0.8, 'vpc': 47.01, 'mpc': 55.0, 'stanje': 2.0, 'aktivan': 255, 'lokacija': '', 'atraktivanod': 0, 'atraktivando': 0}]

for row in dict_list:
    if row.get("sifra"):
        output_dict[row.get("sifra")] = output_dict.get(row.get("sifra"),0) + row.get("stanje", 0)
        
output_dict
```

**Output:**

```
{'7138': 7.0}
```

Comment: I'm getting my data from URL as you can see in my code and I only place this JSON data as example.

I got my full data which you can see if you open link from my code and now I need to SUM data with same ID as explained and export it in new JSON file or XLSX.